# What are the advantages of publishing an RFC

Tags: publishing, technical-writing

I am considering submitting an RFC article to publish [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org). However, I would like to know if there are any advantages that I gain if my article gets published other than bragging rights.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean other than worldwide adoption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will benefit from your article, by providing information and statistics to others who will come across your document; they’ll depend on the numbers and evidence of your article as some readers like what they’re looking into (such as RFC resources) clarified better